# Accessing default values in a domain model using domain services

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to figure out a good and clean way, to give my domain model access to default values defined in my database on creation of new entity objects. Lets say I am using Facebook Connect to create new users for my website. As I can not be sure, that a Facebook user has a country set, I need access to a default country when I create a new entity.

So far, I have created a domain service with a single method, GetDefaultCountry() - more will probably come.

ISettingsService.cs (domain service):

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
    Country GetDefaultCountry();
}
```

The settings service is implemented in the infrastructure layer and can be accessed through my UnitOfWork. Then I have create a factory, which takes a settings service as an argument. This is responsible for the creation of user entities.

UserFactory.cs (domain factory):

```
public class UserFactory
{
    private ISettingsService _settings;

    public UserFactory(ISettingsService settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
    public User CreateFacebookUser(string facebookUserId)
    {
        var user = new User();

        user.AccountType = AccountType.Facebook;
        user.ExternalId = facebookUserId;
        user.Country = _settings.GetDefaultCountry();
        user.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

        return user;
    }
}
```

And this is how my user service looks like.

UserService.cs (application service):

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    UserFactory factory = new UserFactory(uow.GetSettingsService());

    var user = factory.CreateFacebookUser(facebookUserId);
    ...
    uow.Save(user);
    uow.SubmitChanges();
}
```

My question is, am I on the right track? Is it okay to access defaults through a domain service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems fine, although there might be better alternatives depending on your definition of a default country.

- If you want to define the default in code (for instance if Country is a value object), it would be nicer to have something like a static Country.Default property. Less complexity and more fluent than _settings.GetDefaultCountry().
- If Country is a full fledged entity stored in the database with a boolean IsDefault field, my gut feeling is that a Repository would be a better place for the GetDefaultCountry() method. I wouldn't create a Repository just for that though.